# How to get the id in a variable?

Tags: php

I use API SendPulse:

```
$bookName = 'mybook1';
$NewBook = $SPApiClient->createAddressBook($bookName);

$results = var_dump($NewBook);
```

and get an answer

```
object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["id"]=> int(1711458) }
```

how do I get an `id` for later use in code in a variable such as `$myid`?

Comment: `$NewBook->id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an object property

```
$var = $NewBook->id;
```

But why put it in another variable, its an object with a property, so use the objects property where ever you need the data just use `$NewBook->id`